# jquery on select change hide/show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have this select drop-down where in my drop-down when i select one of the choices the div for that particular choice will be displayed and the rest will remain hidden.

I tried using this  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2up7jb3a/)  but it don't work.

```
   <form id="nl-form" class="nl-form">
    <select id="choices">
        <option value="family" selected>family</option>
        <option value="closefriend">close friend</option>
        <option value="acquaintance">acquaintance</option>
    </select>
    <div class="nl-overlay"></div>
    </form>

     <div id="family" class="chosentree">family</div>
     <div id="closefriend" class="chosentree">closefriends</div>
     <div id="acquaintance" class="chosentree">acquaintance</div>

    $(function() {
    $('.chosentree').hide();

    $('#choices').change(function(){
         //$('.chosentree').hide();
         $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
     });
    });
```

What could be the problem?

and also on the div family, I want to place this ff. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3mdszohq/5/) how should it be done? Notice that it has a link script file **check external sources in jsfiddle**

I'm new with this and I don't know what should be the proper placing of codes.

Comment: You have to add jQuery library in first fiddle. Its working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/2up7jb3a/1/

Comment: @Unknown I tried it on localhost but it didn't work also

Comment: you should download jquery code and save as .js file then put on your localhost project and link to your project

Comment: @Singh I have tried that already but it still not working.

Comment: link your file to html page like this <script src="filename.js"></script>

Comment: @Singh I already tried that. I don't know but I tried to check and place an alert inside .change function if it will work but it did not.

Comment: if you don't mind i will solve your problem on remote.

Comment: @Singh what do you mean?

Comment: @Singh I made another http://jsfiddle.net/2up7jb3a/5/ this somehow works fine in jsfiddle but on localhost the alert only works once and when I change the select the alert doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

your code need

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>// you can add what ever is latest version available.
```

since you have written change event better add a dummy select option like:

```
<option value="select" selected>select</option>
```

otherwise it is working.

Here is your working demo after loading above library

[FiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/2up7jb3a/3/)

Comment: does the version of the javascript matter?

Comment: I have loaded already the jquery library still it won't work. I made another demo http://jsfiddle.net/2up7jb3a/5/ it works fine on fiddle but on localhost the alert just shows once when I select one of the dropdowns nothing works.

Comment: for me you code is working check you localhost and see whether all file paths are correct.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by putting

```
$(this.elOriginal).find('option').removeAttr("selected");
                    $(this.elOriginal).find('option:eq('+this.selectedIdx+')').attr("selected", "selected");
                    $(this.elOriginal).trigger('change');
```

in close function in nlform.js

Then by listening to change event of the select element I get my goodies!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but nl-form doesn't actually use the select inputs. If you observe the page in Firebug, you'll notice the actual Select elements have a visibility of "none". What nl-form does is actually take the options in the select that you create and turns them into a series of different html elements (div, a, and ul elements). So when you change an option on an nl-form select, you cannot listen for the change event because it doesn't actually happen.

It turns out it's not real easy or fun to do. What I did to monitor the changes was create a custom event at the bottom of the `close()` method in `nlform.js`. Then in my javascript, I listened for that particular event and had to write a lot of javascript to find the elements I needed...it did eventually work. It's a lot of work though.